# How to ignore null SQL results within BASH?

Tags: sql, bash

I wrote a script that connects to the database and spools a list of orders being delivered to a certain customer and e-mails it to them, but some days the customer won't have any being delivered so they get a blank attachment.

What's the best way so if the SQL results are null then it should skip the customer?

In the script it loops through the account numbers set as a variable:

```
accounts=100...

for i in $accounts {
do

do_data $i
do_mail $i

}
```

SQL like:

```
do_data () {
        sqlplus -s "$user/$pass@$db" <<EOF
        SPOOL $1.csv
        SELECT order_no
        FROM orders
        WHERE customer_number = $1
}
```

Basically if `do_data` outputs nothing then it shouldn't get as far as `do_mail`.

Comment: That doesn't look like BASH script.

Comment: can you measure the size of `$1.csv` somehow? `wc` would seem appropriate if available.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that results are spooled into $1.csv file
Check if the file is not empty and based on that either call do_mail function or not
Make sure that Oracle will not return anything if no data is found

Another way is to alter SQL statement to return string "NO DATA FOUND"
You can check if such string is in output and act accordingly

Comment: Thanks. I am using `-s` but it's showing that the file has data even though it's definitely empty?